# Do we need the axiom of choice if we try to bulid a net $\varphi_{U}$ when $U\rightarrow e$?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, haar-measure

I am confused about the proof for the existence of Haar measure, Cartan gives a proof which avoids using the Axiom of Choice by using filter.

My question is, I try to finish the proof by using the net. I need to build a net in this way.

For all $U$, we can define $\varphi_{U}$ such that $supp(\varphi_{U})\subset U$ by Urysohn Lemma, But for every $U(\ni e)$, we have a lot of $\varphi_{U}$ such that $supp(\varphi_{U})\subset U$. Then to build a net, we actually need that for all $U$, choose a $\varphi_{U}$ From $S_U=\{\varphi_{U}|supp(\varphi_{U})\in U \}$, we can get a net by considering the union of $\varphi_U$ for all $U(\ni e)$. Do we need the axiom of choice here? we just get a choice which is not made in a uniform manner, so I guess we need the axiom of choice here? Or we just give a way to choose every element in every set? I am not sure about that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you come up with a better title to your question? Somethings that tells people what is your question before they read it?

Comment: Probably you can avoid the axiom of choice by making *all* possible choices.  In other words, enlarge your index set to not just be the neighborhoods $U$ but pairs $(U,\varphi)$ where $\varphi$ is a function that works for $U$.

Comment: If we consider (U, $\varphi $) instead of U, I think we still have the same question to choose a net? Am I missing something?